# Race condition between close and send to channel

Tags: go, concurrency, race-condition, goroutine

I'm trying to build a generic pipeline library using worker pools. I created an interface for a source, pipe, and sink. You see, the pipe's job is to receive data from an input channel, process it, and output the result onto a channel. Here is its intended behavior:

1. Receive data from an input channel.
2. Delegate the data to an available worker.
3. The worker sends the result to the output channel.
4. Close the output channel once all workers are finished.

```golang
func (p *pipe) Process(in chan interface{}) (out chan interface{}) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out = make(chan interface{}, 100)
    go func() {
        for i := 1; i <= 100; i++ {
            go p.work(in, out, &wg)
        }
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()

    return
}

func (p *pipe) work(jobs <-chan interface{}, out chan<- interface{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for j := range jobs {
        func(j Job) {
            defer wg.Done()
            wg.Add(1)

            res := doSomethingWith(j)

            out <- res
        }(j)
    }
}
```

However, running it may either exit without processing all of the inputs or panic with a `send on closed channel` message. Building the source with the `-race` flag gives out a data race warning between `close(out)` and `out <- res`.

Here's what I think might happen. Once a number of workers have finished their jobs, there's a split second where `wg`'s counter reach zero. Hence, `wg.Wait()` is done and the program proceeds to `close(out)`. Meanwhile, the job channel isn't finished producing data, meaning some workers are still running in another goroutine. Since the `out` channel is already closed, it results in a panic.

Should the wait group be placed somewhere else? Or is there a better way to wait for all workers to finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you want one worker per job, but if you do, you can restructure your outer loop setup (see untested code below).  This kind of obviates the need for worker pools in the first place.

Always, though, do a `wg.Add` *before* spinning off any worker.  Right here, you are spinning off exactly 100 workers:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
out = make(chan interface{}, 100)
go func() {
    for i := 1; i <= 100; i++ {
        go p.work(in, out, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(out)
}()
```

You could therefore do this:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
out = make(chan interface{}, 100)
go func() {
    wg.Add(100)  // ADDED - count the 100 workers
    for i := 1; i <= 100; i++ {
        go p.work(in, out, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(out)
}()
```

Note that you can now move `wg` itself down into the goroutine that spins off the workers.  This can make things cleaner, if you give up on the notion of having each worker spin off jobs as new goroutines.  But if each worker is going to spin off another goroutine, that worker itself must also use `wg.Add`, like this:

```
for j := range jobs {
    wg.Add(1)  // ADDED - count the spun-off goroutines
    func(j Job) {
        res := doSomethingWith(j)

        out <- res
        wg.Done()  // MOVED (for illustration only, can defer as before)
    }(j)
}
wg.Done() // ADDED - our work in `p.work` is now done
```

That is, each anonymous function is another user of the channel, so increment the users-of-channel count (`wg.Add(1)`) before spinning off a new goroutine.  When you have finished reading the input channel `jobs`, call `wg.Done()` (perhaps via an earlier `defer`, but I showed it at the end here).

**The key to thinking about this is that `wg` counts the number of active goroutines that *could*, at this point, write to the channel.  It only goes to zero when *no* goroutines intend to write any more.**  That makes it safe to close the channel.

---

Consider using the rather simpler (but untested):

```
func (p *pipe) Process(in chan interface{}) (out chan interface{}) {
    out = make(chan interface{})
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    go func() {
        defer close(out)
        for j := range in {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(j Job) {
                res := doSomethingWith(j)
                out <- res
                wg.Done()
            }(j)
        }
        wg.Wait()
    }()
    return out
}
```

You now have one goroutine that is reading the `in` channel as fast as it can, spinning off jobs as it goes.  You'll get one goroutine per incoming job, except when they finish their work early.  There is no pool, just one worker per job (same as your code except that we knock out the pools that aren't doing anything useful).

---

Or, since there are only some number of CPUs available, spin off some number of goroutines as you did before at the start, but have each one run *one* job to completion, and deliver its result, then go back to reading the next job:

```
func (p *pipe) Process(in chan interface{}) (out chan interface{}) {
    out = make(chan interface{})
    go func() {
        defer close(out)
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        ncpu := runtime.NumCPU()  // or something fancier if you like
        wg.Add(ncpu)
        for i := 0; i < ncpu; i++ {
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()
                for j := range in {
                    out <- doSomethingWith(j)
                }
            }()
        }
        wg.Wait()
    }
    return out
}
```

By using `runtime.NumCPU()` we get only as many workers reading jobs as there are CPUs to run jobs.  Those are the pools and they only do one job at a time.

There's generally no need to buffer the output channel, if the output-channel readers are well-structured (i.e., don't cause the pipeline to constipate).  If they're not, the depth of buffering here limits how many jobs you can "work ahead" of whoever is consuming the results.  Set it based on how useful it is to do this "working ahead"—not necessarily the number of CPUs, or the number of expected jobs, or whatever.

Comment: To clarify, no I'm not trying to assign a worker to _each_ job. The idea is that once a worker is finished with its job, it can immediately take another job from the job queue.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the jobs are being completed just as fast as they're being sent. In this case the WaitGroup will be floating near zero even while there's many more items to process.

One fix for this is to add one before sending jobs, and decrement that one after sending them all, effectively consider the sender to be one of the 'jobs'. In this case, it's better if we do the `wg.Add` in the sender:

```
func (p *pipe) Process(in chan interface{}) (out chan interface{}) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out = make(chan interface{}, 100)
    go func() {
        for i := 1; i <= 100; i++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go p.work(in, out, &wg)
        }
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()

    return
}

func (p *pipe) work(jobs <-chan interface{}, out chan<- interface{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for j := range jobs {
        func(j Job) {
            res := doSomethingWith(j)

            out <- res
            wg.Done()
        }(j)
    }
}
```

One thing I notice in the code is that a goroutine is started for each job. At the same time each job processes the `jobs` channel in a loop until empty/closed. It doesn't seem necessary to do both.

Comment: If `wg.Add(1)` is added before `p.work()`, won't `wg` only reach 100? Let's say there are 1000 jobs in queue. Won't `wg` reach 0 after 100 jobs are finished?

Comment: It would, yes. pipe.work's wg.Done should be deferred on its first line, or preferably moves into an anonymous function wrapping the p.work call in pipe.Process so that wg doesn't need to be passed around at all.

Comment: Yes right. You could pass the `wg` to the thing that consumes `out` and call `wg.Done` after each is consumed.

Comment: @icio Yes, that would work. @karmakaze I'm trying to avoid the user of `out` having to deal with any details about `wg`.

Comment: In that case, having the single sender do the `wg.Add` and the processor do `wg.Done` at end makes sense.